# Referencing a CSS File in the HTML Head

Tags: html, css, file

I'm writing a CSS file for the first time. This will be simple. I'd like to know:

A) Should the file just be something like "cssStyle.css"?
B) How would I write it in the HTML so it draws from the .css file in the same folder as all my html files?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In the future please do a little bit of research before posting. Questions should show research effort, be useful and clear.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If index.html and style.css are in the **same** folder

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body> content </body>
</html>
```

If style.css is 1 level up

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" />
```

If style.css is in a folder 1 level up

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../folder/style.css" />
```

If style.css is in a folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/folder/style.css" />
```

For easy inclusion of small css content.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body, html {margin:0}
</style>
</head>
<body> content </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason :( style.css file is in the same folder as homepage.html and I referenced it exactly how you wrote it. The css is written as 'code'#navigation { margin: 100px; }'code'

Comment: It was the damn double quotes in the navigation ID that was messing it up. Thanks for your help. And for anyone else reading it, thanks for their help too. You were all helpful it was my own mistakes with those darn double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To draw it from your html, you want to write this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Inbetween your `head` tags. eg:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

You can name it whatever you want as long as the `href` is the same as the file you called it including the `.css`.

Comment: Is this correct? <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Designs by Dante</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

Forgive me but comment section doesn't let me space.

Answer (score 0):

In head

```
<html>
    <head>
    // link to css and jquery here
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First keep both cssstyle.css file and yourhtml.html in same folder and simply set link tag in your html file

example
yourhtml.html

```
    <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssstyle.css"></link>
  </head>
```